# Chaining element variables for better location in protractor

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

In protractor I'm trying to clean up my locators, and organize things a little better. Currently, I have a variable that contains the element locator for a dialog, and a save button:

```
var StoryPage = function(){
    this.dialog = element(by.css('md-dialog'));
    this.saveButton = element(by.buttonText('Save'));
}
```

My question is, is there a way to chain these element variables, so that I can find the save button within the dialog like so:

```
this.dialog.saveButton.click()
```

or

```
this.dropdown.saveButton.click()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can *chain* the element finders in Protractor:

```
var StoryPage = function() {
    this.dialog = element(by.css('md-dialog'));
    this.saveButton = this.dialog.element(by.buttonText('Save'));
}
```

Now the `Save` button would be located within/in the scope/inside the `md-dialog` element.

---

If you want to "scale" that to multiple page objects, you can define a base page object:

```
var BasePage = function() {
    this.getSaveButton = function () {
        return this.dialog.element(by.buttonText('Save'));
    }
}

module.exports = new BasePage();
```

Then, use *prototypical inheritance* to inherit your other page objects from the base one which would allow you have `save` buttons inside different dialog containers:

```
var BasePage = require("base");

var StoryPage = function(){
    this.dialog = element(by.css('md-dialog'));
}

StoryPage.prototype = Object.create(BasePage);

module.exports = new StoryPage();
```

Comment: I'm aware you can chain elements like that. However, rather than making a `saveDialogButton`, and then a `saveDropdownButton` and so on, I'm wondering if you can have a universal `saveButton`, that you chain after the initial element.

Comment: @ColmGallagher okay, sure. Updated with a sample approach. Hope we are still on the same page (notice the wordplay :)).

Comment: Thanks a million! The prototype idea is exactly what I needed. I just made my account (should have done it years ago), but once I get 15 points I'll make sure you get that upvote you deserve.